# WinSCP error message: Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond - WinSCP has not responded in time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler, winscp

Everyday I get tasks that uses powershell with WinSCP to automate downloading files from clients' sftp, they all work fine on most of the days, except on Saturday (between 7:00 am  and 17:20 pm)

The task that I run is basically looking for new files and then download it, it starts at 5:00 and repeat every 5 minutes for 12 hours in task scheduler and run as Administrator

On Saturday, it starts well (mean I got normal message) at 5:00am and until 7:00 am , I got this error message for every 5 minutes until 17:20

```
Error message: Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond - WinSCP has not responded in time (response log file C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp<some numbers>.tmp was not created). This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself.
```

and after 17:20, I got the normal message:

```
'Synchronise the link file folder

WinSCP.SynchronizationResult

No files synchronised

COMPLETE'
```

I used to get those error message on Saturday

Can anyone help me to fix the issue ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any kind of scheduled tasks on saturday on your server (antivirus full scan or whatsoever) which could slow down or prevent access to files ?

Comment: I do have a full scan (smart scan from ESET file security), it starts at 0:00 and end at 19:00, I also got other WinSCP operation running between 7:00 to 17:20, but they all got the same error message. But how come 5:00 to 7:00 and 17:20 onwards still works, but it didn't work between 7:00 to 17:20? Thank you